# R Precision Arithmetic in GMP, Illegal Operation

Tags: r, crash, fatal-error, gmp, abort

I'm attempting to use the function `as.bigq()` in R's `gmp` package, but it always causes an "illegal operation". For example, if I run the following code:

```
library(gmp)
as.bigq(1)
```

it triggers

```
*** caught illegal operation ***
address 0x11ffc8b21, cause 'illegal opcode'

Traceback:
 1: as.bigq(1)

Possible actions:
1: abort (with core dump, if enabled)
2: normal R exit
3: exit R without saving workspace
4: exit R saving workspace
```

I've never encountered anything like this in all my years using R, and am hopelessly confused. Someone's response to a [vaguely similar issue](https://github.com/rstudio/keras/issues/309) involves the BLAS being used. Here are the details of my current session:

```
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin17.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Monterey 12.6

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2/Resources/lib/libRblas.0.dylib
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] gmp_0.6-6

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_4.2.1
```

Comment: I can't reproduce, but I'm on Linux with `BLAS/LAPACK: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openblas-pthread/libopenblasp-r0.3.20.so`. Try re-installing `gmp` from source?

Comment: I cannot reproduce on a Mac either, also with gmp_0.6-6 . Agree need to reinstall gmp. The only difference I see is that I'm on macOS Monterey 12.5.1

Comment: @IRTFM I reinstalled from source, and even tried various versions of the package, but have had no luck. I was actually able to recreate the problem on a different Mac. It may be a complete shot in the dark, but could the error be related to both machines having Apple's relatively new silicon chips opposed to intel chips?

Comment: You should probably review postings to r-sig-Mac mailing list.